# Preview Assemble (plus Yeoman and Grunt) project in development without rebuild

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, assemble

I'm really new to the Grunt plugin Assemble, and indeed Grunt itself. Assemble looks potentially useful for a project I'm starting, but I have one (probably very newb-ish) question.

Having generated a site using the Assemble generator for Yeoman, is there a way of viewing changes without using Grunt to rebuild every time? My feeling is there is a way of watching the project directory for changes, and doing some kind of partial (i.e. assemble -> HTML pages, SASS -> CSS etc) build on changes, but I have yet to find it...

**Update** I'm homing in on something, it seems like grunt-contrib-watch might be what I'm after...

**Update** If anyone with the requisite reputation sees this, would it be worth creating an assemble (or assemble.io) tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case it helps someone else, creating a 'watch' Grunt task (using grunt-contrib-watch) was indeed what I needed.

There's an excellent tutorial on creating an Assemble project [here](http://www.gpmd.co.uk/blog/front-end-process-flat-builds-and-automation-part-1-introduction/), and the same guy (Matt Bailey) has put together a Yeoman generator that's sets up a project as per the guide, [here](https://github.com/matt-bailey/generator-bones)